# Foreach loop dynamically changes server connection only once in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm writing an SSIS package that loops through a list of servers collecting inventory information.

The package (in theory) should

- Get a list of servers
- Connect to each one in a foreach
- Runs a simple query for inventory purposes and save information to a temp table
- Log this information to a static server

The issue that I'm running into is that the package is only changing the connection one time, then it is maintaining this connection through the whole foreach.

The initial connection is

```
Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=master;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;
```

This connection is never actually used except to fool SSIS into believing the temp table already exists on the server at package start time, even though the package itself creates the table.

Within the properties of this connection I have set

```
ServerName = @[User::ServerName]
InitialCatalog = @[User::Database]
```

The Database variable is actually just hardcoded to "master", but I used a variable for future easy changes if it should need to be changed.

Anyways, I query my static connection for the list of servers and map the result set to a variable User::ServerList (which is of type object).

On the foreach loop I have the enumerator set to Foreach ADO Enumerator with the ADO object source variable User::ServerList.  In the Variable mappings I have User::ServerName at Index 0, which is a variable of type string and is not initially set to anything.

I have single stepped through each foreach loop iteration, and the ServerName variable is indeed changing on each loop.  The connection changes to the first server connection and happily performs its duties (I have confirmed this by manually checking the temporary table results on the server, the table is created and populated).

However, upon the next iteration - I see the ServerName variable change to the appropriate server, and the package happily executes... but it didn't actually change the dynamic connection, I discovered this by querying the next server to see that the table didn't exist.  I went to the previous server and queried it again, and sure enough the table still existed and the Date variable I keep int he table had changed to be slightly more recent.

The connection for each of the tasks within the foreach loop is set to be the "DynamicConnection" and I'm certain that it actually does change on the first iteration, because the first server in the list *is not* localdb.

Any idea on why this might be occurring?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I suspect you can only set a connection's connection string once per package run.  You might need to move this logic into a script task to get it to work.

Comment: @TabAlleman Sorry what do you mean by move the logic into a script task?  Have a script set the connection string variable and such?

Comment: Exactly, instead of using a package connection and changing its connection string, run a script that creates a connection, uses it for whatever tasks are needed, and then destroys it.

Comment: @TabAlleman Would you know of any places that I can see an example of this? Fairly new to SSIS and an example to follow along with would be great.

Comment: Not off the top of my head.   I'd start with searching `create connection in SSIS script task`.

Comment: @TabAlleman I discovered the error!  I have the "RetainSameConnection" variable of the connection manager set to true (as I am dealing with a temporary table).  Is there a way to explicitly close a connection in SSIS?

Comment: No way I know of, but then I've never really searched for one either, so you might try that.